# how to move data from one source to another source with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, filesystems, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to know how files are in one folder move to another folder. Here, python script sense that files got inserted and should move to another folder.

**how can we automate the process?**

I tried with simple python code:

```
import shutil
import os

source = '/directory&files/directory1/'
dest = '/directory&files/directory1/sample/'

files = os.listdir(source)

if len(files) == 10:
   for f in files:
    shutil.move(source+f, dest)   
else:
    print('Have no file exist or More files to be append')
```

Is any of doing this automate process using of multiprocessing, queue or signals? etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can using While True with sleep, for checking files:

```
import time
while True:
    if len(files) == 10:
       for f in files:
        shutil.move(source+f, dest)   
    else:
        print('Have no file exist or More files to be append')
    time.sleep(5) #delay time in sec
```

Comment: when the same directory used in another code. It's throwing an error.
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:/auto_directory&files/directory1/AppsTek/aak-2021-04-07_05-09-47_PM.txt'

Comment: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:/auto_directory&files/directory1/AppsTek/aak-2021-04-07_05-09-47_PM.txt' - @vieegg

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog),
Take a look at the [documentation](https://python-watchdog.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.3/quickstart.html) to see how to use it